# Repeat certain pandas series values, so that it has an entry for all index values between 1 and 100

Tags: arrays, pandas, numpy

I have created a list of pandas series, with each series indexed by numbers between 1 and 100 eg

```
Index    Value
1        62.99
4        64.39
37       75.225
65       88.12
74       89.89
79       93.30
88       94.30
92       95.83
100      100.00
```

What I want to do, either while it is a Series, or as an array after calling .to_numpy() on it, is to fill it out so that my series has 100 values (1 to 100), with any new entries having the previous existing value ie

```
Index    Value
1        62.99
2        62.99
3        62.99
4        64.39
5        64.39
6        64.39
...
...
36       64.39
37       75.225
38       75.225
```

and so on.

I can do this programmatically the long-winded way by iterating through each series and checking for a change in value; my question is, is there a version of Series.repeat() which could do this in one hit, or a numpy function which can 'pad out' my array in this manner with my 100 values?

Thanks in advance for reading, and for any suggestions. This isn't homework; it's a genuine question so please don't attack me if my style of asking isn't as you expect.

Comment: ```df.reindex(range(df.index.min(), df.index.max() + 1), method="pad")``` ?

Comment: sammywemmy, that absolutely nailed it - thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need yo do is to frontfill the values in a series:
This code

```
series = pd.Series([33.2, 36, 39, 55], index=[3, 6, 12, 14], name='series')

indices = range(100)
df = pd.DataFrame(indices)

series = df.join(series).ffill()['series']
```

produces

```
0      NaN
1      NaN
2      NaN
3     33.2
4     33.2
      ... 
95    55.0
96    55.0
97    55.0
98    55.0
99    55.0
```

First values ar NaN because there are no values to fill them in the series

Comment: Thank you dberezin, this also works a treat. Really useful to know about ffill() and bfill() too. Hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

So here's the solution I went with - an ffill() with fillna(0), joining to range(1,101). I had to iterate through a larger dataset which needed grouping by ID first / taking the maximum 'Pct' per 'Bucket' :-

```
j=df[['ID','Bucket','Pct']].groupby(['ID','Bucket']).max()
for i in df['ID'].unique():
    index=pd.DataFrame(range(1,101))
    index.columns=['Bucket']
    k=pd.merge(index,j.loc[i],how='left',on='Bucket').ffill().fillna(0)


In:
Bucket  Pct
3       0.03
3       0.1
3       0.26
3       0.42
3       0.45
3       0.59
3       0.69
3       0.83
3       0.86
3       0.91
3       0.94
3       0.98
4       1.1
...       ...
91      98.89
93      99.08
94      99.17
94      99.26
94      99.43
94      99.48
94      99.63
100     100.0

Out:
Bucket  Pct
1       0.00
2       0.00
3       0.98
4       1.83
5       22.83
...     ...
91      98.89
92      98.89
93      99.08
94      99.63
95      99.63
96      99.63
97      99.63
98      99.63
99      99.63
100     100.00
```

Many, many thanks once again to you both!